# Ghostscript output save location

Tags: python, ghostscript

I'm trying to use ghostscript in python. This is my code:

```
import sys
import ghostscript

args = [
    "-sDEVICE=jpeg",
    "-sOutputFile=test-%d.jpg",
    "-dBATCH", "-dNOPAUSE",
    "/users/arnoutaertgeerts/downloads/langetest.pdf"
    ]

ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args)
```

But I can't find the generated images (I can see them being generated though!) I did some tests and apparantly it doesn't matter what I type at -sDEVICE... So something most be wrong?
I'm using Ghostscript 9.0.6

Where does ghostscript save my images?

Comment: I can see ghostscript converting the images with X11 (mac)

Comment: They are located in the 'current' directory (wherever you are executing the script from probably) as you haven't specified a different location. If you want them put elsewhere, then supply a full path in -sOutputFile=<path>/<filename>.jpg. Does this imply that your other problem (can't find libgs) is now resolved ?

Comment: yeah, I looked for the libgs in my folders and added it to the path but now GS still doesn't work :)

Comment: Try using the command line directly. Your post above makes it seem like it is working though, what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Since your args don't have -dSAFER you should be able to specify the full path, including a full path with a directory (as you have for the input file) in. Try -sOutputFile="/users/arnoutaertgeerts/test-%d.jpg"

Then look in your  /users/arnoutaertgeerts directory.